# Maximum number of TCP connections on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, sockets, ubuntu, tcp

I'm developing a java server on AWS virtual machines (ubuntu) which will be used for an online android game. I have done a test that showed me maximum ~4080 client can connect to the server. I get the "SocketException : too many files open", if more clients want to connect. I checked the number of limits: "ulimit -n" gives me 1024. Changing it to the 4096 didn't make change.

A new thread is created for any accepted socket and they do nothing currently and are alive until I stop the server.

After all 4080 connections are established, I observe that about 1gb of ram is used. I have total of 2gb.

How can we handle more tcp connections? Is my multithread approach useful or I should follow a different approach for thousands of clients?

Comment: Without seeing code I can not comment. Though, looks like you are opening new socket each every time request coming in.

Comment: @bobs_007 your guess is correct.

Comment: @user3703595 You question is a bit more  about configuring your OS than a specific java question. None the less, you might check for example if you need a socket for any new client. Have you heard about java nio? ( http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/01/nio.html )

Comment: @Jägermeister thanks for link. Is there any other way of handling multiple clients rather than opening a new socket for each client?

Answer (score 0):

ulimit variables are not actually a system wide parameters. They are set as per process attributes and being nested by children. Please ensure you run your java server from process which already has raised ulimit.

Comment: How can I do that? I just typed ulimit -n 4096 as root.

Comment: As you are able to start 4080 clients, I thinks this is not the issue. You need to run ulimit __before__ you start your JAVA process in that same shell

Answer (score 0):

Every child process on UX inherits all open file descriptors from it's parent. Spawning a child as a client for networking is a bit tricky as you need to close all unnecessary descriptors in the child explicitly (I.e. 0, 1, 2 for stdin, out and err).

This also relates to open sockets (from the good old "everything is a file" policy), so if you have a listener on a socket and spawn a child, it already has this socket open. You may the duplicate this socket, but need to close the original in the child etc.